Counts repetitions within a list
We have a list from Subsets[Prime[Range[10]], {2}]:
{{2, 3}, {2, 5}, {2, 7}, {2, 11}, {2, 13}, {2, 17}, {2, 19}, {2, 
  23}, {2, 29}, {3, 5}, {3, 7}, {3, 11}, {3, 13}, {3, 17}, {3, 
  19}, {3, 23}, {3, 29}, {5, 7}, {5, 11}, {5, 13}, {5, 17}, {5, 
  19}, {5, 23}, {5, 29}, {7, 11}, {7, 13}, {7, 17}, {7, 19}, {7, 
  23}, {7, 29}, {11, 13}, {11, 17}, {11, 19}, {11, 23}, {11, 29}, {13,
   17}, {13, 19}, {13, 23}, {13, 29}, {17, 19}, {17, 23}, {17, 
  29}, {19, 23}, {19, 29}, {23, 29}}

Let's sum each pair up next:
Plus @@@ Subsets[Prime[Range[10]], {2}]

{5, 7, 9, 13, 15, 19, 21, 25, 31, 8, 10, 14, 16, 20, 22, 26, 32, 12, \
16, 18, 22, 24, 28, 34, 18, 20, 24, 26, 30, 36, 24, 28, 30, 34, 40, \
30, 32, 36, 42, 36, 40, 46, 42, 48, 52}

Now let's see which sums match:
Last /@ Select[Gather[Plus @@@ Subsets[Prime[Range[10]], {2}]], Length[#] > 1 &]

16, 20, 22, 26, 32, 18, 24, 28, 34, 30, 36, 40, 42

However, I need the simplest expression to return the number of times (in descending order) that each pair matches up:
For example:  {3,13} and {5,11} ===> 2
and 3 other sets matched up 3 times to this SUMS ==> {24, 30, 36} ...find which 3 pairs are in the set.

To be more specific: GroupBy[Total][Subsets[Prime[Range[10]], {2}]] /@ {24, 30, 36}

GroupBy[s1, Total] // KeySort // Select[GreaterThan[1]@*Length] where s1 = Subsets[Prime[Range[10]], {2}];

{# -> IntegerPartitions[#, {2}, Prime[Range[10]]]} & /@ Range[2, 40]

Hi Whoever closed this question, the reference you provided gives a list of numbers giving a particular SUM.   This is more. I need to sort all SUMs of pairs in descending order and list them ALL< not just a particular SUM.   Thanks @Syed for the solution above!!!  Would be nice to count them next...like 24 has a total of 3 sets, etc

Group has an argument to reduce the list of generated values. Try:  GroupBy[s1, Total, Length] // KeySort @Steve237

@Syed  plz post as answer and I will vet....above is convoluted...Thx

I like these sorted by the Lengths,  this does not do that: GroupBy[s1, Total, Length] // KeySort  -- will KeySortBy be needed?

"I need to sort all SUMs of pairs in descending order and list them ALL" Do you mean GroupBy[Total][Subsets[Prime[Range[10]], {2}]] // Reverse?

Thanks @xzczd for the tip. It was quite late so I crashed out. This morning I see plenty of answers already.

Option 1: Organized by sum:
data = Subsets[Prime[Range[10]], {2}];
ReverseSortBy[GroupBy[data, Total, Comap[{Length, Identity}]], First]
(* <|36 -> {3, {{7, 29}, {13, 23}, {17, 19}}}, 
     30 -> {3, {{7, 23}, {11, 19}, {13, 17}}}, 
     24 -> {3, {{5, 19}, {7, 17}, {11, 13}}}, 
     42 -> {2, {{13, 29}, {19, 23}}}, 
     40 -> {2, {{11, 29}, {17, 23}}}, 
     34 -> {2, {{5, 29}, {11, 23}}}, 
     32 -> {2, {{3, 29}, {13, 19}}}, 
     28 -> {2, {{5, 23}, {11, 17}}}, 
     26 -> {2, {{3, 23}, {7, 19}}}, 
     22 -> {2, {{3, 19}, {5, 17}}}, 
     20 -> {2, {{3, 17}, {7, 13}}}, 
     18 -> {2, {{5, 13}, {7, 11}}}, 
     16 -> {2, {{3, 13}, {5, 11}}}, 
     52 -> {1, {{23, 29}}}, 
     48 -> {1, {{19, 29}}}, 
     46 -> {1, {{17, 29}}}, 
     31 -> {1, {{2, 29}}}, 
     25 -> {1, {{2, 23}}}, 
     21 -> {1, {{2, 19}}}, 
     19 -> {1, {{2, 17}}}, 
     15 -> {1, {{2, 13}}}, 
     14 -> {1, {{3, 11}}}, 
     13 -> {1, {{2, 11}}}, 
     12 -> {1, {{5, 7}}}, 
     10 -> {1, {{3, 7}}}, 
     9 -> {1, {{2, 7}}}, 
     8 -> {1, {{3, 5}}}, 
     7 -> {1, {{2, 5}}}, 
     5 -> {1, {{2, 3}}}|> *)

Option 2: Organized by number with same sum:
data = Subsets[Prime[Range[10]], {2}];
KeySortBy[GroupBy[GatherBy[data, Total], Length, Map[Comap[{First/*Total, Identity}]]], Minus]
(* <|3 -> {{24, {{5, 19}, {7, 17}, {11, 13}}}, 
           {30, {{7, 23}, {11, 19}, {13, 17}}}, 
           {36, {{7, 29}, {13, 23}, {17, 19}}}}, 
     2 -> {{16, {{3, 13}, {5, 11}}}, 
           {20, {{3, 17}, {7, 13}}}, 
           {22, {{3, 19}, {5, 17}}}, 
           {26, {{3, 23}, {7, 19}}}, 
           {32, {{3, 29}, {13, 19}}}, 
           {18, {{5, 13}, {7, 11}}}, 
           {28, {{5, 23}, {11, 17}}}, 
           {34, {{5, 29}, {11, 23}}}, 
           {40, {{11, 29}, {17, 23}}}, 
           {42, {{13, 29}, {19, 23}}}}, 
     1 -> {{5, {{2, 3}}}, {7, {{2, 5}}}, {9, {{2, 7}}}, 
           {13, {{2, 11}}}, {15, {{2, 13}}}, {19, {{2, 17}}}, 
           {21, {{2, 19}}}, {25, {{2, 23}}}, {31, {{2, 29}}}, 
           {8, {{3, 5}}}, {10, {{3, 7}}}, {14, {{3, 11}}}, 
           {12, {{5, 7}}}, {46, {{17, 29}}}, {48, {{19, 29}}}, 
           {52, {{23, 29}}}}|> *)


Something like the following, maybe?
(Ordered first by Length and then by Total, lowest-to-highest within each category)
data= SortBy[MapAt[
  Splice@{Length[#], #} &, {All, 
   2}]@({#, GroupBy[lst, Total][#]} & /@ 
   Union[(Total /@ lst)]), {#[[2]], First} &][[All, {2, 1, 3}]];

    Grid[data, Alignment -> Left]

    1   5   {{2,3}}
    1   7   {{2,5}}
    1   8   {{3,5}}
    1   9   {{2,7}}
    1   10  {{3,7}}
    1   12  {{5,7}}
    1   13  {{2,11}}
    1   14  {{3,11}}
    1   15  {{2,13}}
    1   19  {{2,17}}
    1   21  {{2,19}}
    1   25  {{2,23}}
    1   31  {{2,29}}
    1   46  {{17,29}}
    1   48  {{19,29}}
    1   52  {{23,29}}
    2   16  {{3,13},{5,11}}
    2   18  {{5,13},{7,11}}
    2   20  {{3,17},{7,13}}
    2   22  {{3,19},{5,17}}
    2   26  {{3,23},{7,19}}
    2   28  {{5,23},{11,17}}
    2   32  {{3,29},{13,19}}
    2   34  {{5,29},{11,23}}
    2   40  {{11,29},{17,23}}
    2   42  {{13,29},{19,23}}
    3   24  {{5,19},{7,17},{11,13}}
    3   30  {{7,23},{11,19},{13,17}}
    3   36  {{7,29},{13,23},{17,19}}


Alternatively, to sort by highest-to-lowest within each category (Length first, followed by Total)
Grid[ReverseSortBy[
 MapAt[Splice@{Length[#], #} &, {All, 
  2}]@({#, GroupBy[lst, Total][#]} & /@ 
  Union[(Total /@ lst)]), {#[[2]], First} &][[All, {2, 1, 3}]], 
 Alignment -> Left]


    3   36  {{7,29},{13,23},{17,19}}
    3   30  {{7,23},{11,19},{13,17}}
    3   24  {{5,19},{7,17},{11,13}}
    2   42  {{13,29},{19,23}}
    2   40  {{11,29},{17,23}}
    2   34  {{5,29},{11,23}}
    2   32  {{3,29},{13,19}}
    2   28  {{5,23},{11,17}}
    2   26  {{3,23},{7,19}}
    2   22  {{3,19},{5,17}}
    2   20  {{3,17},{7,13}}
    2   18  {{5,13},{7,11}}
    2   16  {{3,13},{5,11}}
    1   52  {{23,29}}
    1   48  {{19,29}}
    1   46  {{17,29}}
    1   31  {{2,29}}
    1   25  {{2,23}}
    1   21  {{2,19}}
    1   19  {{2,17}}
    1   15  {{2,13}}
    1   14  {{3,11}}
    1   13  {{2,11}}
    1   12  {{5,7}}
    1   10  {{3,7}}
    1   9   {{2,7}}
    1   8   {{3,5}}
    1   7   {{2,5}}
    1   5   {{2,3}}



where
lst=Subsets[Prime[Range[10]], {2}]


great work @user1066 -- by the way how do we get these to print per each line?  ex: get a newline after each comma in the output?

You can use GroupBy, e.g.
using
list = {{2, 3}, {2, 5}, {2, 7}, {2, 11}, {2, 13}, {2, 17}, {2, 
    19}, {2, 23}, {2, 29}, {3, 5}, {3, 7}, {3, 11}, {3, 13}, {3, 
    17}, {3, 19}, {3, 23}, {3, 29}, {5, 7}, {5, 11}, {5, 13}, {5, 
    17}, {5, 19}, {5, 23}, {5, 29}, {7, 11}, {7, 13}, {7, 17}, {7, 
    19}, {7, 23}, {7, 29}, {11, 13}, {11, 17}, {11, 19}, {11, 
    23}, {11, 29}, {13, 17}, {13, 19}, {13, 23}, {13, 29}, {17, 
    19}, {17, 23}, {17, 29}, {19, 23}, {19, 29}, {23, 29}};

You can use third argument:
GroupBy[list, Total, {Length@#, #} &]

yielding:
<|5 -> {1, {{2, 3}}}, 7 -> {1, {{2, 5}}}, 9 -> {1, {{2, 7}}}, 
 13 -> {1, {{2, 11}}}, 15 -> {1, {{2, 13}}}, 19 -> {1, {{2, 17}}}, 
 21 -> {1, {{2, 19}}}, 25 -> {1, {{2, 23}}}, 31 -> {1, {{2, 29}}}, 
 8 -> {1, {{3, 5}}}, 10 -> {1, {{3, 7}}}, 14 -> {1, {{3, 11}}}, 
 16 -> {2, {{3, 13}, {5, 11}}}, 20 -> {2, {{3, 17}, {7, 13}}}, 
 22 -> {2, {{3, 19}, {5, 17}}}, 26 -> {2, {{3, 23}, {7, 19}}}, 
 32 -> {2, {{3, 29}, {13, 19}}}, 12 -> {1, {{5, 7}}}, 
 18 -> {2, {{5, 13}, {7, 11}}}, 
 24 -> {3, {{5, 19}, {7, 17}, {11, 13}}}, 
 28 -> {2, {{5, 23}, {11, 17}}}, 34 -> {2, {{5, 29}, {11, 23}}}, 
 30 -> {3, {{7, 23}, {11, 19}, {13, 17}}}, 
 36 -> {3, {{7, 29}, {13, 23}, {17, 19}}}, 
 40 -> {2, {{11, 29}, {17, 23}}}, 42 -> {2, {{13, 29}, {19, 23}}}, 
 46 -> {1, {{17, 29}}}, 48 -> {1, {{19, 29}}}, 52 -> {1, {{23, 29}}}|>

You can manipulate Association as you see fit.
